# get value from excel sheet in c# pie chart

Tags: c#, winforms, pie-chart

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(testingExcel, Type.Missing, true);
_Worksheet xlWorksheet = (_Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

foreach (Range c in xlRange.Rows.Cells)
{
    chart1.Series["MultiUser"].Points.AddXY(c.Value, c.Value);
}
xlWorkbook.Close();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I have taken pie chart in C# windows application .

When I run this code it is giving only first raw that is pass, failed, skipped, warning at right side but not giving value in chart.

This is my chart input:

[image]

[Pie Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJJku.jpg)

Comment: Could not understand your problem. Please rephrase it. If possible show the pie chart image.

Comment: Pie chart image added